# Is it possible to find the joint distribution of a random vector if only the distribution of scalar many-to-one transformation is known?

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution, jacobian

Theoretical Exercise:

I'd like to derive the joint distribution $p_{\boldsymbol{X}}$ of a random vector $\boldsymbol{X} \in \mathbb{R}^K$ if only the distribution of a scalar many-to-one transfomration is known, say, $f(\boldsymbol{X}) = Y \sim p_Y$, with $Y \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Is it possible to find the density $p_{\boldsymbol{X}}$? Are there any assumptions that are necessary to find $p_{\boldsymbol{X}}$? One assumption that would be OK for my specific problem at hand is, for example, a uniform distribution assumption for all vectors $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ that account for the same value $y^*$ of $Y$.

Practical Exercise:

Maybe it's best to clarify that with an example?

Say, we have $Y = \sum_{i = 1}^K \boldsymbol{X}_i$ and $Y \sim Gamma(K, \lambda)$. Is it possible to derive $p_\boldsymbol{X}$ if we assume $X_1, \dots, X_K$ to be iid? That is, is it possible to show that $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Expo(\lambda)$, for $i = 1, \dots, K$?

I found a [nice intuitive introduction](http://andymiller.github.io/2015/08/09/integral-jacobian.html) showing $Y = \sum_{i = 1}^K \boldsymbol{X}_i$ is Gamma distributed, if $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Expo(\lambda)$. I think I understood the method but I cannot manage to go the opposite way. So maybe I didn't. The last issue where I stuck was to find a one-to-one mapping that makes sense to compute the Jacobian.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Your example seems to ask about **deconvolution**, which is different from the question in the title (and first paragraph). Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm also interested in this, I think that it's not possible in general. If you see [my question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367903/z-is-a-non-linear-transform-of-x-i-know-the-distribution-of-z-is-it-possible-t), there's a great example by @whuber, where if you know that $Z = f(X) \sim U(0, 1)$ and $Z = |X|$, then any one of these can be true $X \sim U(0, 1)$, $X \sim U(-1, 0)$, $X \sim U(-1, 1)$